# MySQL count date

Tags: mysql, date, count

Why is this happening

Shouldn't this query retrieve the number of records until a specifc date?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE date < 2013-01-01
```

I have several records on the db that match the query, however, the count comes 0

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE date < DATE('2013-01-01')

Comment: What is the data type of your `date` column?

Comment: @sdespont please post a formal answer as you were the first to comment, so I can give you an accept! Thank you! that solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your string as a date using `DATE`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE date < DATE('2013-01-01')
```

Comment: I'm intrigued to know how taking the date part of a date literal makes the slightest difference whatsoever?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `date` < '2013-01-01'
```

If date column's date format is not same as in where clause then use FORMAT_DATE function to make them similar.

Comment: I think you meant to say: "*if column is not of a date type then **fix your schema***"?

Comment: eggyal:no i meant if its not in the format '2013-01-01' then make it in this format in select query only for matching purpose

Comment: if date formats are different then it wont match thats why i suggested to make them in same format

Comment: Well, for a start, if `date` is not already a temporal data type then one cannot apply `DATE_FORMAT()` to it.  Perhaps you meant to use `STR_TO_DATE()`?  However, such a function call is very expensive to process and cannot be aided by indexes.  Not to mention that it's terrible practice to store dates as strings in the first place, which is really the poor advice I was trying to address.

Comment: oops sorry yes I ment to use this STR_TO_DATE().

Comment: yeah but I thought OPs table structure cant be changed and hence asked to convert that in select statement